# How to replace the first and the last ',' delimiter with '||' from a csv while leaving the others as it is?

Tags: python, regex

I have a CSV file:

```
101, "Name1", "Designation1", "blah1", "Blah1", 20200914001
102, "Name2", "Designation2", "blah2", "Blah2", 20200914002
103, "Name3", "Designation3", "blah3", "Blah3", 20200914003
104, "Name4", "Designation4", "blah4", "Blah4", 20200914004
105, "Name5", "Designation5", "blah5", "Blah5", 20200914005
```

replace each line like below:

```
101|| "Name1", "Designation1", "blah1", "Blah1"|| 20200914001
```

similar structure goes to the rest of the lines/records as well.

My code replaces all of the delimiters.

```
data = ""
with open('firstCSV.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace(',', '||').replace(' ', '')

with open("first_Out.csv", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(data)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
^([^,]*),|,(?=[^,]*$)
```

Replace with `\1||`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/HLHdQa/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##NY7BCsIwEETv@YpQhCQSJKlePBRBPPsDaqWFpQ20admsoNB/j2XR2xtmmJn5Q/0U9zmHcZ6QJIIQCB28ZSVR1fpW28fW2MXqU8W8MUoQJHomQs54560srs0IvljhAil0saEwRdbt0PQM5x@UrnTu6A/OeSXSq03ENXe/LErMGCJphN1qaP5hJWes/I8ak/MX):

```
import re

regex = r'^([^,]*),|,(?=[^,]*$)'
test_str = r'101, "Name1", "Designation1", "blah1", "Blah1", 20200914001'
subst = r'\1||'
print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

Result: `101|| "Name1", "Designation1", "blah1", "Blah1"|| 20200914001`.

Comment: The typical regex warning applies here: use with caution. In the example provided, this will work as intended. In a CSV file where your data has commas in quoted strings ``"Doe, John"` in either the first or last column, you'll be in for an unexpected surprise...

Comment: Thanks @Ryszard, in my current requirement, this helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could split on the first (`maxsplit=1` from the left) and last (`maxsplit=1` from the right) commas and join the results, e.g.:

```
>>> line = '101, "Name1", "Designation1", "blah1", "Blah1", 20200914001'

>>> first, rest = line.split(',', maxsplit=1)
>>> rest, last = rest.rsplit(',', maxsplit=1)
>>> '||'.join((first, rest, last))
'101|| "Name1", "Designation1", "blah1", "Blah1"|| 20200914001'
```

Comment: This solution also comes with the caveat that it won't work if the first or last field is a quoted string that includes a comma.